# regex pattern to match a url in php

Tags: php, regex

i need help with this regex pattern. I have tried many different patterns but none return anything. I always get an empty array. The following patterns return no results.

```
//test 1    
$regex = '/linkDestUrl = \'(.*)\'/';

//test 2
$regex = '@^(?:\s)*(linkDestUrl = \'(.*)\');@mi';
```

to match this

```
linkDestUrl = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Comment: Try `$regex = "/^linkDestUrl\s*=\s*'(.*)'$/";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if its that simple, this should work:

```
$search = "linkDestUrl = 'http://www.google.com';";
preg_match_all("/linkDestUrl = '(.*)';/im", $search, $result);
var_dump($result[1]);
```

Try it out on http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

Comment: I added this `$search = file_get_contents("http://go.urlcash.net/uxbmt0fxegk");` to replace `$search = "linkDestUrl = 'http://www.google.com';";` but it didn't work. How did you set it up?

Comment: @bammab see the updated answer. You should have been more specific. I add the multiline switch and the case insensitive switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a site like http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test your reg exp